# Symfony doesn't load my custom validator defined as service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to inject EntityManagerInterface in my custom validator, but I have this error:

```
Attempted to load class "validator_check_client_id" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

[image]

My code is:

**CheckClientId.php**

```php
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */

class CheckClientId extends Constraint{
    public $message = 'Test';
    
    public function validatedBy(){
        return 'validator_check_client_id';
    }
}
```

**CheckClientIdValidator.php**

```php
namespace App\Validator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CheckClientIdValidator extends ConstraintValidator{
    private $entityManager;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint){
        //Todo
        return;
    }
}
```

**services.yaml**

```yaml
    validator.check_client_id:
        class: App\Validator\CheckClientIdValidator
        autowire: false
        arguments:
            $entityManager: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        tags:
            - {
                  name: validator.constraint_validator,
                  alias: validator_check_client_id,
              }
```

Should I do an extra step to register my service? I think that symfony cannot find it because it is not properly registered.

I also tried to do what this answer says [symfony validator as service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862237/symfony-validator-as-service-not-working/46221737#46221737), but I get a similar error:

```
Attempted to load class "app.validator.blog.slug_unique" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Do you have any idea what is happening?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tried with `return 'validator.check_client_id';` (note the dot instead of the first underscore)?

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Constraint::validatedBy needs to return the fully qualified name of your validator class.  Something like: [return static::class.'Validator';](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#creating-the-validator-itself). Better yet, just follow the Symfony naming convention and let the default code work.  Then your validator service needs to use the same class name as the service id.  If you just remove your configuration from services.yaml and let autowire do it's job then it should just work.

Comment: If I use return 'validator.check_client_id'; I have the error: Attempted to load class "validator.check_client_id" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 5.2

Comment: If I use return static::class.'Validator'; I have the error Too few arguments to function CheckClientIdValidator::__construct(), 0 passed in ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 43 and exactly 1 expected  dependencies in your constraint validator you have to register as a service.

Comment: If you need to use dependencies in your constraint validator you have to register as a service https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies

Comment: From the above link: If you’re using the default services.yaml configuration, then your validator is already registered as a service and tagged with the necessary validator.constraint_validator. This means you can inject services or configuration like any other service. ... In other words, you don't need to register it as a service.  Trying to use validator.check_client_id is what is causing your troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to autowire and autoconfig, all you really have to do is to get your class names right.  No changes to services.yaml.  Here is a working example using a fresh 5.2 project.

```
# src/Validator/CheckClientId.php
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/** @Annotation */
class CheckClientId extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'CheckClientId';
}
# =============================
# src/Validator/CheckClientIdValidator
namespace App\Validator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;

class CheckClientIdValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {

    }
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        dump('validate ' . $value);
        throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'string');
    }
}
# ===============================
# Test Entity
# src/Entity/Client.php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Validator as AcmeAssert;

class Client
{
    /** @AcmeAssert\CheckClientId */
    public $id = 42;
}
# ====================================
# Test Command
# src/Command/ValidateCommand
namespace App\Command;

use App\Entity\Client;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class ValidateCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'test:validator';

    public function __construct(private ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($client);
        echo $errors;

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Get the test command working and move on from there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I replicated your code in my project and although it worked in the console, it did not work for me when I tried it in the browser, so I changed the way I was validating, again thank you very much! :)